# python search in csv using headers with spaces

Tags: python, csv

When I use a column name with space in row, the script does not print anything however if I use a column name without space, the script prints the result. How can I use headers with space?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import os
import fnmatch

rootdir = '/var/www/html/storage/DATA/'
pattern = 'file**.csv'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files,pattern):
                path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(path) as f:
                        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
                        for row in reader:
                #if row['newColor'] == 'blue': #This works.
                if row['cid number'] == '998': #This does not work.
                        print(row['oldColor'])


Sample Data
market    brand    type    newColor    oldColor    cid number    length
SFO    6754    x    blue    orange    998    6
CHI    6754    x    green    black    932    6
ATL    6766    x    blue    yellow    822    6
```

Comment: What does your CSV format look like? Post the first few lines.

Comment: Added some sample data. Sorry for the formatting, I don't know how to paste an excel data here.

Comment: are you delimited by a space, or are there spaces in your data that you do not want?

Comment: The data is delimited by comma since it is a csv file I am dealing with. I paste it here with spaces so it makes more sense how my data looks. Looks like I am failing to make sense :) basically when I put a column name without space it gives me the correct values but when I try to search in using the column name 'cid number' which has a space, it doesn't print anything on the console.

Comment: If the data is delimited by comma in the file, then your "sample data" is garbage. SHOW US YOUR RAW CSV FILE CONTENTS. I don't care what it looks like after you read it in and format it nicely.

Comment: Your csv file fails csvlint, but is valid if you put quote marks around "cid number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your csv file is delimited by comma (which you say it is) then it should look something like this:

```
market,brand,type,newColor,oldColor,cid number,length
SFO,6754,x,blue,orange,998,6
CHI,6754,x,green,black,932,6
ATL,6766,x,blue,yellow,822,6
```

If this is the case, then your code should work as is (assuming the indentation is correct). If your csv looks like what you pasted, that is, delimited by spaces, then the `cid number` is treated as two separate columns `cid` and `number`.

I would print out each row in your `for row in reader` loop to confirm the keys of the dictionary